# How do I perform map of array in Javascript while transforming one part of return object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a React component which is performing a get operation of a JSON and returning an array with this format of object:

```
{
device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e"
device_type: "MX480"
domain: "JUNIPER"
domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6"
resources: null
sync_status: "idle"
sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00"
}
```

What I need to do is transform the `sync_time` in each returned object to a date/time format which I have successfully converted using the following:

```
const finalSyncDates = names.map(item => new Date(item.sync_time))
.map(n => n.toLocaleString());
```

But I still need the rest of the object. Ultimately I want to output:

```
{
device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e"
device_type: "MX480"
domain: "JUNIPER"
domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6"
resources: null
sync_status: "idle"
sync_time: "CONVERTED SYNC TIME HERE"
}
```

Just not sure of the syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you return in the function gets returned. You need to only change one part of the object.

```js
const finalSyncDates = names.map(item => {
  return { ...item,
    sync_time: new Date(item.sync_time).toLocaleString()
  };
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
const names = [{
  device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e",
  device_type: "MX480",
  domain: "JUNIPER",
  domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6",
  resources: null,
  sync_status: "idle",
  sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00"
}, {
  device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e",
  device_type: "MX480",
  domain: "JUNIPER",
  domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6",
  resources: null,
  sync_status: "idle",
  sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00"
}, {
  device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e",
  device_type: "MX480",
  domain: "JUNIPER",
  domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6",
  resources: null,
  sync_status: "idle",
  sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00"
}];
const finalSyncDates = names.map(item => {
  return { ...item,
    sync_time: new Date(item.sync_time).toLocaleString()
  };
});
console.log(finalSyncDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this mate**

In `map()` function you can change the desired property of object ( current element ) and than simply you can return the element.

```js
let obj = [{
          device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e",
          device_type: "MX480",
          domain: "JUNIPER",
          domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6",
          resources: null,
          sync_status: "idle",
          sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00",
         },
         {
          device_id: "5c07f86f-3763-477f-81a7-558395a9252e",
          device_type: "MX480",
          domain: "JUNIPER",
          domain_id: "5c07f843-7e67-4ce1-bf91-d0d7b04f35f6",
          resources: null,
          sync_status: "idle",
          sync_time: "2018-12-10T19:18:20+00:00",
         }]


let op = obj.map(e=>{
  e.sync_time = new Date(e.sync_time).toLocaleString();
  return e;
})


console.log(obj);
```